# DF insertInto is not persisting all columns for mixed structured data ( json, string)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

DataFrame saveAsTable is persisting all the column values properly but insertInto function is not storing all the columns especially json data is truncated and sub-sequent column in not stored hive table.

Our Environment

- Spark 2.2.0
- EMR 5.10.0
- Scala 2.11.8

The sample data is

```
 a8f11f90-20c9-11e8-b93e-2fc569d27605   efe5bdb3-baac-5d8e-6cae57771c13 Unknown E657F298-2D96-4C7D-8516-E228153FE010    NonDemarcated       {"org-id":"efe5bdb3-baac-5d8e-6cae57771c13","nodeid":"N02c00056","parkingzoneid":"E657F298-2D96-4C7D-8516-E228153FE010","site-id":"a8f11f90-20c9-11e8-b93e-2fc569d27605","channel":1,"type":"Park","active":true,"tag":"","configured_date":"2017-10-23
 23:29:11.20","vs":[5.0,1.7999999523162842,1.5]}
```

**DF SaveAsTable**

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark SQL Test").
config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").
config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").
enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

val zoneStatus = spark.table("zone_status")

zoneStatus.select(col("site-id"),col("org-id"), col("groupid"), col("zid"), col("type"), lit(0), col("config"), unix_timestamp().alias("ts")).
write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("dwh_zone_status")
```

Stored data properly in result table:

```
a8f11f90-20c9-11e8-b93e-2fc569d27605    efe5bdb3-baac-5d8e-6cae57771c13 Unknown E657F298-2D96-4C7D-8516-E228153FE010    NonDemarcated   0   {"org-id":"efe5bdb3-baac-5d8e-6cae57771c13","nodeid":"N02c00056","parkingzoneid":"E657F298-2D96-4C7D-8516-E228153FE010","site-id":"a8f11f90-20c9-11e8-b93e-2fc569d27605","channel":1,"type":"Park","active":true,"tag":"","configured_date":"2017-10-23 23:29:11.20","vs":[5.0,1.7999999523162842,1.5]} 1520453589
```

**DF insertInto**

```
zoneStatus.
  select(col("site-id"),col("org-id"), col("groupid"), col("zid"), col("type"), lit(0), col("config"), unix_timestamp().alias("ts")).
  write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("zone_status_insert")
```

But insertInto is not persisting all the contents. The json string is storing partially and sub-sequent column is not stored.

```
a8f11f90-20c9-11e8-b93e-2fc569d27605    efe5bdb3-baac-5d8e-6cae57771c13 Unknown E657F298-2D96-4C7D-8516-E228153FE010    NonDemarcated   0   {"org-id":"efe5bdb3-baac-5d8e-6cae57771c13"  NULL
```

We are using insertInto functions in our projects and recently encountered when parsing json data to pull other metrics. We noticed that the config content is not stored fully. Planning to change to saveAsTable but we can avoid the code change, if any workaround available to add in spark configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that schema created with

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

After removing the ***ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','*** can able to save entire contents using insertInto.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below alternative ways of inserting data into table.

```
val zoneStatusDF = zoneStatus.
  select(col("site-id"),col("org-id"), col("groupid"), col("zid"), col("type"), lit(0), col("config"), unix_timestamp().alias("ts"))

zoneStatusDF.registerTempTable("zone_status_insert ")
```

Or

```
zoneStatus.sqlContext.sql("create table zone_status_insert as select * from zone_status")
```

Comment: I tried both approaches which you mentioned but got the same results.

Comment: Hi Ravi, What is the o/p from zoneStatusDF.limit(5).show ? Does all the columns data displayed correctly? Can you paste the o/p